# Move databases on same Mac

Tags: mysql-5.5, mac-os-x

I have just updated my MacBook to Mountain Lion. Since then, my MAMP installation does not work properly so I decided to use the build httpd/php stuff. For this, I have additionally installed a new mysql server (following [this](http://coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion) tutorial). Everything runs very well. Now my question is, how to use my old databases in my new server? I tried to create a new database which creates a folder "databasename". Into this folder I moved all the .frm files, corrected rights and owner and started mysql, but unfortunately, phpmyadmin does not recognize the tables... did I something wrong? Alternatively, I would just set the data directory of the new mysql server to my old directory, but I cannot find the my.cnf file :-( Where is it stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to export the databases from the MAMP server and import them to your new database server.

Here's a guide with MySQL dump and restore: http://www.patrickpatoray.com/?Page=30